# "Calculations on/about the limiting behaviour"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> I did some calculations ___ the limiting behaviour of some functions, when n tends to infinity.

Is it *about*, *on*, or even something else?

Comment: Both are acceptable, but you could use "for" either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you specifically did, you may have more specific words other than *about*, or *on*:

- I did some calculations **defining** the limiting behaviour of some functions, when n tends to infinity.
- I did some calculations **constraining** the limiting behaviour of some functions, when n tends to infinity.
- I did some calculations **projecting** the limiting behaviour of some functions, when n tends to infinity.
- I did some calculations **deducing** the limiting behaviour of some functions, when n tends to infinity.
- I did some calculations **reducing** the limiting behaviour of some functions, when n tends to infinity.
- I did some calculations **perceiving** the limiting behaviour of some functions, when n tends to infinity.
- I did some calculations **over** the limiting behaviour of some functions, when n tends to infinity.
- I did some calculations **predicting** the limiting behaviour of some functions, when n tends to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

"on" sounds somewhat more academic than "about" to my ear.

> I did some calculations [**on**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=calculations+on+the%2Ccalculations+about+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccalculations%20on%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccalculations%20about%20the%3B%2Cc0) the limiting behaviour of some functions, when n tends to infinity.